# Export SDF database contents as JSON file

Tags: c#, xml, json, winforms, sql-server-ce

I have a C# Windows Forms project which uses a SQL Server Compact (`.SDF`) database for only retrieving data. My application does not update the database. Thus the database is static.

I recently read somewhere that for such kind of static work it is best to use XML or JSON as they reduce the I/O time which is spent on connecting to the database, retrieving,and closing the database. Is this true?

If So, is there a way by which I can directly convert my database contents to that of a JSON file? It has 7 tables(relations) now and total of 850 rows(tuples) of data. The data is in Kannada language and not English (if this makes any diff).

Comment: What kind of operations are you doing on the data? Do you join the tables? Would building 7 lists of classes and using LinQ-to-objects be fast enough?

Comment: I am just retrieving data from each table...no join operations...simple `Select * from table A where ID = <user input>`

Comment: I dont know about the LinQ - to - objects concept

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with 850 read-only records that you don't join, reading from a file rather than a database is way faster.

What you want to do is save your data in files (one per table will come in handy) and read them once at program start into a list of classes that look like your respective table structure. You can then operate on those lists a lot faster than on a database. You can use JSON as a file format, or XML or CSV if your data is simple, or anything else you can come up with.

*How* you do this in detail is way to broad as a question for this site. Read a few turorials and ask a more detailed question once you have any problems with it.

Comment: So, Is there a way in which i can use existing data stored in my database for creating a JSON file ?

Comment: Sure. Get on google and read a tutorial. Your question is too broad for a Q&A site such as this.